# Unexpected behavior of the Canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I have some code for example. That contains two buttons. I have bind the on_press event for btn, and on click I tried to change its Scale. But in fact this code somehow changes size of btn1 instead btn. I do not know why

```
class TutorialApp(App):

    scale = 1
    def btn_click(self, elem):

        if self.scale < 0.2: return

        sc = Scale()
        sc.xyz = (0.8,0.8,1)
        self.scale *= 0.8
        print self.scale
        elem.canvas.add(sc) #after и canvas has same behavior, but before changes scales of both buttons/ I don't know why


    def build(self):
        bl = Layout(text='APP')
        bl.orientation = 'vertical'
        btn = Button(text='OK', size_hint=(1,0.5))
        btn1 = Button(text='OK1', size_hint=(1,0.5))

        btn.bind(on_press = self.btn_click)

        bl.add_widget(btn) #,pos=(100,100)
        bl.add_widget(btn1) #,pos=(100,100)

        return bl
```

I have tried to employ `after` or `before`, and by `elem.canvas.after` behavior is same as without them, by `before` I get changes size of the both buttons. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `elem.canvas.add(sc)` appends the `Scale` to the list of instructions for `btn`. So it doesn't affect the drawing of `btn`, but does affect the drawing of `btn1` (since it is drawn after `btn`). Using `canvas.before` inserts the `Scale` before the `btn` drawing, so it affects both. Obviously, using `canvas.after` has the same effect as the original.

Comment: So why `canvas.after` has the same effect as the original? What's the difference between them? Why did the creators of the framework create `canvas.after` if there is the `canvas` that does not differ in behavior

Comment: The Kivy widgets do their drawing using `canvas`. You can draw stuff before that using `canvas.before` or after that using `canvas.after`. In your case, adding the `Scale` to the end of the `canvas` instructions is effectively equivalent to adding it to the beginning of the `canvas.after`.